# Streamlit st.button Loop

Tags: python, callback, streamlit

i have some issue with st.button used inside a an enumerate lopp.

I have st.button inside a dataframe, on click i want the value of the button to be changed and a dataframe to be updated. Except that when i click i have multiple loop on my callback function.

To simplify here i take a say_hello function. here when I click i have 3 lines printed. But i can't figure out why. Thnks

```
def say_hello(x):
     print("hello : " + x)  

user_table = {
'N' : [1,2,3],
'email' : ["aa@gmail.fr","bb@gmail.fr","cc@gmail.fr"],
'uid' : [1,2,3],
'verified' : ["yes","no","yes/no"],
'disabled' : ["hh","pp","kak"]
}      
         
colms = st.columns((1, 2, 2, 1, 1))
fields = ["№", 'email', 'uid', 'verified', "action"]
for col, field_name in zip(colms, fields):
    # header
    col.write(field_name)

for x, email in enumerate(user_table['email']):
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = st.columns((1, 2, 2, 1, 1))
    col1.write(x)  # index
    col2.write(user_table['email'][x])  # email
    col3.write(user_table['uid'][x])  # unique ID
    col4.write(user_table['verified'][x])   # email status
    disable_status = user_table['disabled'][x]  # flexible type of button
    button_type = "Unblock" if disable_status else "Block"
    button_phold = col5.empty()  # create a placeholder
    do_action = button_phold.button(button_type, key=x,on_click=say_hello(user_table['email'][x]))
    if do_action:
         pass # do some action with a row's data
         button_phold.empty()
```

Comment: When you press a button, it would trigger streamlit to run your code from top to bottom. Hence your loop will be executed. 3 lines will be printed because user_table['email'] has 3 items. See [streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/main-concepts) concept. This is normal. You have to adjust to get what you wanted. This is how streamlit works.